# Hudson to send alerts about its own problems

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson

Hudson is a great tool, and the emails it sends about failing builds are a great help. However, it can only do this if Hudson itself is in a working condition. It is able to report problems with its own executors like low disk space, unsynced clocks etc. on the web interface, just as it reports build problems, but I couldn't find an option to send email alerts about these. Yet it would be so useful, and seems so logical that this feature *should* be there.

Am I looking at the wrong place to fix this? Is there another solution to learn about problems with executors without having to poll the web interface every now and then? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check all of the plugins?

Did you ask on the  http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Mailing%20List   ?

Personally, much as I love Stack Overflow, I only use it after I have exhausted more dedicated possilities such aa a dedicated foru, mailing lists, emailing the author(s)/maintainer(s) ..

Sorry.

Btw, I have been using Hudson for years and and say that there is - IMO _ mothing better.

As a last resort, maybe you can hack the source code? This sounds like a reasonable feature so I am sure that your code would be slipstreamed into the main build; failiing that, package it as a plug-in

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the remote API from Hudson. http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Remote+access+API

You can use it to query the statuses you want programatically. You can also file your request as a hudson issue or document it with the [The new emailer plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/The+new+EMailer)